# Retrieving String SharedPreference in BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, broadcast

I'm trying to get a String from an EditText in my BroadcastReceiver class from a normal Activity. The thing is SharedPreferences are really confusing me, this is how I have it set up right now. It works to save the string and all, but I can't retrieve it.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

        savedLocation = getSharedPreferences("location", MODE_PRIVATE);

        mZipCodeET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_area);

        mZipCodeET.setText(savedLocation.getString("tag", "")); 
        // @param 2 is default value of the edit text

        mZipCodeET.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    Time time = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                    time.setToNow();
                    mLastRefreshTV.setText("Last Refresh: " + time.format("%k:%M:%S"));

                    String EditTextString = mZipCodeET.getText().toString();
                    searchByPlaceName(EditTextString);

                    if(mZipCodeET.getText().length() > 0) {
                        makeTag(EditTextString);    

                        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                            .hideSoftInputFromWindow(mZipCodeET.getWindowToken(),0);

                        }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

And in there it calls the makeTag() method

```
private void makeTag(String tag){
     String or = savedLocation.getString(tag, null);
     SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedLocation.edit();
     preferencesEditor.putString("tag",tag); //change this line to this
     preferencesEditor.commit();
 }
```

I just want to retrieve that string and assign it to another string in my onReceieve() method in my Broadcast class, if you could help, and explain that'd be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In broadcast receiver's onReceive method, a context object is received. You can use that context to fetch the sharedPreference string as :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent data) {
SharedPreferences shared= context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERS_NAME,0);
String tag= shared.getString("tag",null);
}
```

Or if you had a made a util class for SharedPreferences then pass there the context object.